# MongoCursor size is decreasing when it is converted to list using toList

Tags: mongodb, cursor, casbah

I am having weird issue with mongo cursor. I am using casbah to access Mongo through Scala code. I have following code:

```scala
val cur = collection.find(MongoDBObject("brand" -> "someBrand")

val items = cur.toList.map(dbo => ScalaJack.readDB [ T ] (dbo))
```

I have 387 item in the db that should be returned with the query above. But it is returning 364 items only. When I checked the size of `cur` it is 387, but when I checked the size of `cur.toList` it is 364.

I am not sure why doing `toList` on cursor is decreasing the size. What might cause it?

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401597/casbah-cursor-and-tolist

Comment: Can you provide a test case?  How did you check the size of `cur`? What does `collection.find(MongoDBObject("brand" -> "someBrand")).count()` return?  Also can you try a `foldLeft` as well? `collection.find(MongoDBObject("brand" -> "someBrand")).foldLeft(0)((x, doc) => x+1)` Finally what type of mongodb setup do you have single node or sharded?